# Pandas extract value from a key-value pair

Tags: pandas

I have a Datafrmae with output as shown below, I am trying to extract specific text

```
id,value
101,*sample value as shown below*
```

I am trying to extract the value corresponding to key in this text

Expected output

```
id, key, id_new

101,Ticket-123, 1001
```

Given below is how the data looks like:

```
{
    'fields': {
        'status': {
            'statusCategory': {
                'colorName': 'yellow',
                'name': 'In Progress',
                'key': 'indeterminate',
                'id': 4
            },
            'description': '',
            'id': '11000',
            'name': 'In Progress'
        },
        'summary': 'Sample Text'
    },
    'key': 'Ticket-123',
    'id': '1001'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html):

```
df['key'] = df['value'].str.get('key')
df['id_new'] = df['value'].str.get('id')
print (df)
    id                                              value         key id_new
0  101  {'fields': {'status': {'statusCategory': {'col...  Ticket-123   1001
```

Tested `Dataframe`:

```
v = {
    'fields': {
        'status': {
            'statusCategory': {
                'colorName': 'yellow',
                'name': 'In Progress',
                'key': 'indeterminate',
                'id': 4
            },
            'description': '',
            'id': '11000',
            'name': 'In Progress'
        },
        'summary': 'Sample Text'
    },
    'key': 'Ticket-123',
    'id': '1001'
}
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':101, 'value':[v]})
```

Comment: thanks for reply.. I had tried `.str.get()` method but it returned all `NaN`

Comment: @scottmartin - is possible use `import json` and `df['value'] = df['value'].apply(json.loads)` befor my solution?

Comment: that returns `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'`

Comment: @scottmartin - hmmm, it means there are dictionaries, not strings. If test outpu tof one value like `print (df['value'].iat[0])` it is same output like in question? Or some another `{}` or `[]` ?

Comment: there are few null rows. However row that has data returns data within `[]`

Comment: @scottmartin - Hard question, what is wrong. I guess some data related problem. Added data tested from sample.